# Can't save code in text field, WordPress

Tags: wordpress, textfield

I need to put some extra code in text field in a wordpress theme. I tried saving it on text tab and on visual tab, nothing worked. After I have saved it, it's no longer there. Even after I toggled from text tab to visual tab and back, the code would disappear. What could be a solution for such a problem?

Comment: What does the extra code look like?

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question! I put first this to the text fileld `<a href="http://test.bootwalksnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/0098-d-11.jpg"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-201" alt="0098 d 11" src="http://test.bootwalksnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/0098-d-11.jpg" width="290" height="104" /></a>` and it was ok. But then I was needed to have this code `<span class="et_overlay"></span> ` before the `</a>` and I couldn't save it there. It keeps disappearing.

Comment: I use fancybox plugin for the popups for the images by the way.

Comment: hmm. I will test this out later tonight. Confirm for me that you are using the standard WP WYSIWYG editor (or let me know if you tweaked that element). Off the top of my head I forget the when/why on the editor's odd behavior + I have no WP sandbox at work to test this for you.

Comment: No, it's not standard WYSIWYG, it's in a text module of a special plugin.

Comment: details on that please.

Comment: it's the elegantthemes Elegant Page Builder plugin, you install the theme and then install the plugin and within that you have various modules including the text module. Like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this out on my sandbox install and the default editor is simply stripping out empty tags. The most easy workaround is to, unfortunately, not make the tags empty in a way that the editor will remove them.

By placing this html in the **text** :

```
A:<span class="et_overlay"></span>
B:<span class="et_overlay"> </span>
C:<span class="et_overlay">&nbsp;</span>
D:<span class="et_overlay"><!----></span>
E:<span class="et_overlay"><!-- --></span>
F:<span class="et_overlay"><!-- X --></span>
```

switching to the **visual** tab and back again to **text** tab the results look like :

```
A:
B:
C:<span class="et_overlay"> </span>
D:
E:<span class="et_overlay"><!-- --></span>
F:<span class="et_overlay"><!-- X --></span>
```

So - a "pure" space or any comment that is not `<!---->` (note the lack of space) will hold the span.

This apparently is the case for any empty tag. I found a number of references to this in SO and other sites.  There was a bug report file here :

http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5269

On may 12, 2012. I think it is dead or on ignore?

There are a few workarounds beyond my above demo. Some after martket plugins (meh, you decide)  - review these links https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52582/how-to-disable-tinymce-from-removing-span-tags and http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-stop-wp-stripping-out-empty-div-tags among many.

You could hack the core/javascript. Not a fan of that / avoid.

Should you "solve" this problem, I feel that you might open up another can of worms. Other users or the editor will start to haunt you in your sleep as the ability to remove "dead" tags will be gone and the various elements that truly need to be stripped will remain, haunting you to your grave.

Ok, that is a mild exaggeration, but the tag stripping might be a key to a greater user experience in the context of a user who needs none of these fancy features that you are apparently tapping into.

If I was going to have a non-html/programmer (typical) user who would need to add spans as outlined I would write a short-tag function in functions.php that would turn this :

```
[span class="et_overlay"]
```

into

```
<span class="et_overlay"><!-- --></span>
```

It would only take about 8 lines of code to accomplish (yeah Wordpress). Hope this helps or someone else has something positive to add.

Comment: Thanks you very much for such a research! You know this example with &nbsp; really did help, it remained in place after save. I hope these people will be satisfied with this data and would not haunt me. Though the effect I wanted to achieve didn't come out, the class apparently doesn't work this way, now I know where to look for the possible answer. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, thx for the green check mark.  I welcome ay other suggestions or ideas to this thread.